# Automatically Create tmp/restart.txt for Dreamhost Flask Application

Tags: flask, pycharm, passenger, dreamhost

I have a flask application that I am running on a Dreamhost server.  I am using PyCharm's deployment tools to manually and/or automatically update the files on the server when changes are made.

When running a flask app on Dreamhost with Passenger, the app is cached and so the only way for Passenger to know to refresh the cache is for the tmp/restart.txt file to have a new timestamp.  Manually, this is done from the terminal via SSH with `touch tmp/restart.txt`.

But I would like to somehow accomplish this automatically from within PyCharm.  Is there a way to do that?  I can't find anything.

I saw someone suggest that they can do this via github: "For my projects I add a post-receive hook into my git repo to touch the file for me."  Frankly, I don't really know what that means, but I think it means this is "easy" if I were deploying to github and then somehow syncing to the Dreamhost server from there.

But it also suggests that there could be a way to do this in PyCharm.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is part of [a professional feature on Pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-a-remote-server-configuration.html).

Also, learning to deploy via Github Actions (or Bitbucket Pipelines or tools like CircleCI etc) will have lots of future benefits because you can make complicated deployments (and also testing, if you like) an automatic step.

So let me share how to use Github Actions to deploy a Flask application to Dreamhost.

Firstly create in your project's root folder, a file called .github/workflows/main.yml

In this file we will specify instructions to deploy the updated code files from your github repository to your dreamhost server using rsync. Github will spawn a temporary ubuntu instance to run these instructions. We will also run some post-deployment steps like running pip and installing dependencies from `requirements.txt` after activating the virtual environment, and also touching the restart.txt file.

<main.yml>

```
name:  Deploy to Dreamhost on Push

# Controls when the workflow will run
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on push events and only for the master branch
  push:
    branches: [ master ]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  # This workflow contains two jobs
  rsync-deploy:
    name: ️ Rsync with Dreamhost
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
    # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
    - name:  Get Latest Code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    # Send files to webserver via rsync
    - name:  Rsync files
#      uses: Pendect/action-rsyncer@v1.1.0
      uses: burnett01/rsync-deployments@5.1
      with:
        switches: -avzr --delete --exclude='venv/' --exclude='.git/' --exclude='.github/'
        path: /
        remote_path: /home/yourdreamhostusername/yourwebsite.com/
        remote_host: yourwebsite.com
        remote_user: yourdreamhostusername
        remote_key: ${{ secrets.DREAMHOST_SSH_KEY }}

    # Install any new dependencies from requirements.txt
    - name:  Install Python Dependencies
      uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
      with:
        host: yourwebsite.com
        username: yourdreamhostusername
        key: ${{ secrets.DREAMHOST_SSH_KEY }}
        port: 22
        script: |
          cd /home/yourdreamhostusername/yourwebsite.com
          source venv/bin/activate
          pip3 install -r app/requirements.txt
          touch /home/yourdreamhostusername/yourwebsite.com/tmp/restart.txt
```

Replace `yourwebsite.com` and `yourdreamhostusername` appropriately, also you have to SSH in and create the virtual environment (here it's assumed you have previously SSH'd in and created the venv in the folder `/home/yourdreamhostusername/yourwebsite.com/venv/` on your Dreamhost account). Lastly you will also need to create an SSH key (public and private key pair). Upload the private key to dreamhost in the .ssh folder and the private key to Github secrets as `DREAMHOST_SSH_KEY`.